# How to display in django admin readonly data from other model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Why when i call instance of model from method `car_name` the method return `-` in Django admin.

```
@admin.register(Invoice)
class CarProductDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CarProductDataAdminForm

    def car_name(self, obj):
        # Call this instance 
        car = Customer.objects.get(product__customer_id=self.request.user.person.id)
        return "car.name"  # return string

    readonly_fields = ('car_name', )
```

But when i just return string it is work.

```
@admin.register(Invoice)
class CarProductDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CarProductDataAdminForm

    def car_name(self, obj):
        # Doesn`t Call this instance 
        # return string
        return "name"

    readonly_fields = ('car_name', )
```

Comment: what is the result of `print(car.name)`?

Comment: this is print nothing

Comment: Which means, the `Customer` object instance(the variable `car`) that you have doesn't hold any value

Comment: no, i was update question. It is has been doesn't call even when a returned value is string.

Answer (score 0):

From my judgement the django admin seems to fail silently when encountering an exception in a method, which is used as a field.

In your first example the problem seems to be `self.request`, as the `CarProductDataAdmin` instance does not have a `request` attribute. So instead of raising an exception no value is returned to the field resulting in an output "-".

If you need the `request` you must get it from somewhere and save it in your `ModelAdmin` for re-use. Maybe by overring the `get_form` method of the ModelAdmin

```
class CarProductDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

# ....

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        return super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
```

Then you should be able to use your `car_name` method as posted in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First noticeable problem in your code is that instead of object attribute value you are returning a string:

```
return "car.name"  # return string
```

should be:

```
return f"{car.name}"
```

or, depending on python version you are using:

```
return f"{}".format(car.name)
```

Next one is that calling `get` on model manager should cause DoesNotExists exception but in some situations it could be suppressed so I'll advice to modify the code to:

```
try:
    car = Customer.objects.get(product__customer_id=self.request.user.person.id)
    return f"{car.name}" 
except Customer.DoesNotExists:
    return "None"
```

And see if that return what you want or "None"